# Show Fragment on First Launch

Tags: android, android-fragments, boolean, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to show a fragment only on the first time the application is launched. What I'm trying works to show the fragment but it always shows, I only want it to show on first launch.
 I'm replacing fragments from a method called `displayView`, in a navigation drawer drawerlistener (this may be my problem), im trying to use a boolean and shared preferences in my method. Any ideas as to why this isn't working

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            firstTimeFrag();
        }
    }
    private boolean firstTimeFrag(){
        SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean ranBefore = pref.getBoolean("RanBefore",false);
        if(!ranBefore){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.commit();
        Fragment fr = new ifFirstTimeFrag();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }else{
            displayView(0);
        }
    return ranBefore;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You are not saving anything ^^**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.commit();
```

Use this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Oh, um, that's embarrassing, lol yeah that works now ;-) great catch thank you very much